# Implementing PHP code into a function

Tags: php, function, ssh, phpseclib

I have some code that I want to make into a function, as I want to use it with different parts of my code and on different pages, and I don't want to have to have the code everywhere.  I am using the PHPseclib library and class. The code that works on its own is:

```
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('$address');
if (!$ssh->login('$username', '$password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}


$sPath = "minecraft/servers/";
$sSavingCode = "server.properties";
$motd = "test";

echo $ssh->exec("cat > $sPath$sSavingCode <<EOF
motd=".$motd."
EOF
");
```

I want to make this into a function, so I tried doing this:

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
    include('phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php');

```
 $ssh = new Net_SSH2('$address');
    if (!$ssh->login('$username', '$password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }    
function test($motd)
    {
        $sPath = "minecraft/servers/";
        $sSavingCode = "server.properties";

        $ssh->exec("cat > $sPath$sSavingCode <<EOF
        motd=".$motd."
        EOF
        ");
    }
```

with the rest of the code outside and above the function. I am trying to call the function like:

```
$motd = "Server";
test($motd);
```

But that comes back with a server error. Is this function possible? Or should I just put the code where I need it every time I want to use it?

Comment: what is the error it returns?

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: I would assume its an undefined error since in your function you don't have a defined $ssh variable to call exec on

Comment: try $GLOBALS['ssh'].exec or define a local copy in your test function global $ssh;

Comment: I have edited the function code to show that the $ssh is defined, yet the server is still throwing a Error 500

Comment: Where should I put $GLOBALS['ssh'].exec?

Comment: Using global scope is one way to do it, but as a best practice it's better to avoid doing so. I believe it's even being removed from PHP6.

Comment: Good question as I suspect that people coming from JavaScript expect '$ssh' to be accessible from within test() automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function has a dependency on `$ssh`, so it should be passed as an argument:

```
function test(Net_SSH2 $ssh, $motd)
{
    $sPath = "minecraft/servers/";
    $sSavingCode = "server.properties";

    $ssh->exec("cat > $sPath$sSavingCode <<EOF
    motd=".$motd."
    EOF
    ");
}

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('$address');
// ... 
test($ssh, $motd);
```

Comment: Is this a better method than using `global $ssh;` in the function?

Comment: @Runner Using global variables is a bad programming practice; if you need access to more variables, it would be better to group them together into objects and pass that around.

Comment: This is a good answer. Consider what happens if you want to use the original $ssh inside a different function or, what if the function changes? What if the variable $ssh is global scoped elsewhere by someone else by mistake? Also, consider the scenario where you might want to connect to a different $address using the same function or use the same function to call a different address.

Comment: Thank you, this works well now. Should I put the $ssh in the file where the function is, or the file where I call the funtion?

Comment: @Runner where you define $ssh itself doesn't matter so much. It can be created somewhere else entirely before being passed into the function.

Answer (score -1):

you are accessing a local $ssh variable when you want the $ssh variable you defined outside of your function.

so in your function declare  'global $ssh' and use that otherwise you are trying to call exec on a local, which is undefined.

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('$address');
if (!$ssh->login('$username', '$password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}    
function test($motd)
{
    global $ssh;
    $sPath = "minecraft/servers/";
    $sSavingCode = "server.properties";

    $ssh->exec("cat > $sPath$sSavingCode <<EOF
    motd=".$motd."
    EOF
    ");
}
```

Alternatively, the predefined php array $Globals allows you to access these variables without defining a local var

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('$address');
if (!$ssh->login('$username', '$password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}    
function test($motd)
{

    $sPath = "minecraft/servers/";
    $sSavingCode = "server.properties";

    $GLOBALS['ssh']->exec("cat > $sPath$sSavingCode <<EOF
    motd=".$motd."
    EOF
    ");
}
```

Comment: This function absolutely should have the $ssh variable passed to it in its parameters. Making it global takes away from the functions re-usability.

Comment: sure, doesnt take away from the validity of my answer. shouldnt downvote a perfectly valid answer depending on how he wants to implement it

Comment: Thank you. This way worked, but I think I will go with the other way as it seems to have more functionality and mobility.